# Which permission is required to post on facebook main wall or timeline through personal website c#?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-permissions

Which permission is required to post on facebook main wall or timeline through personal website c#?
like pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_posts is required for posting on Fb Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By “main wall” you mean the user profile timeline?

That is not possible any more via API, that has been removed a while ago.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#login-4-24:

> The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the permission until August 1st, 2018. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this date, we encourage you to use our [Sharing products](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing) instead.

Comment: Yes I mean profile timeline but through Graph API we can post on Facebook pages with other permissions like pages_read_engagement,pages_manage_posts

Comment: You can post to pages, but not to user profiles, not any more.